# Retrieve Category & Subcategory list in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to HTML, PHP & MySql, so apologies for the noob question but, I need to retrieve categories from a database, that are in 2 tables, but am having difficulty calling the subcategories after clicking the initial link.

```
//Category code as...

<?php

require 'dbcon.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `category`";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

echo "<table>
  < tr >
  <th>Category < /th>
  < /tr>";

while ($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()) {
  $id = $row['category_ID'];

  echo "<td><a href=\"subcategory.php?id=$id\">" .$row['description']. "</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

?>


//Subcategory code as...

<?php
require 'database_conn.php';
$sql = "SELECT category.ID, subcategory.title, subcategory.ID FROM category, subcategory WHERE subcategory.ID=category.ID";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

echo "<table>
  < tr >
  <th>Title < /th>
  < /tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['title']. "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Ideally, I would like it so that selecting one category will bring up the whole list of subcategories, either in the same page or a separate page. I've struggled over this for a few days now and I'm really struggling to understand what it is I am doing wrong.

Comment: best way to do this using `ajax`. try to doing this using ajax this type of resources available in the web.

Answer (score 0):

simply take the id from the URL and put into your query

```
$category_id = $_GET['id'];
SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE category_id = $id;
```